# Boost.Python static method overloads

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

How do I expose the following class using Boost.Python?

```
class C {
 public:
  static void F(int) {}
  static void F(double) {}
};
```

I tried something like this:

```
bp::class_<C>("C")
  .def("F", (void (C::*)(int))&C::F).staticmethod("F")
  .def("F", (void (C::*)(double))&C::F).staticmethod("F")
;
```

But, it raises an exception in Python (`SystemError: initialization of libdistributions raised unreported exception`).  If I remove one of the overloads from the `bp::class_`, then everything works fine.  I know that Boost.Python can automatically deal with overloaded constructors, so I was wondering if there was something like that for static methods.

---

## Answer

```
bp::class_<C>("C")
  .def("F", (void (C::*)(int))&C::F)  // Note missing staticmethod call!
  .def("F", (void (C::*)(double))&C::F).staticmethod("F")
;
```

Comment: Please post the exception that is being raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here you can find the solution to your problem:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html#python.overloading

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the fact of them being static methods was important.  I need to call staticmethod once despite there being two methods!